# PHP, Close cmd window after code executed via popen

Tags: php, cmd, terminal, exec, popen

This should be a common problem but I couldn't find any straight answer for it!

**The main goal is** to run a PHP script and output to a command prompt window, then close the window by the end of the execution. **The problem is** I couldn't find a way to close the terminal window afterwards!

On windows, I have two php files `script_1.php` and `script_2.php`. script_1 opens a new cmd window which will run script_2 (asynchronously obviously). I use `popen` to run commands. This is the contents of `script_1.php`:

```
<?php
pclose(popen('cmd /c start cmd.exe /k php script_2.php ' . $this->request_id, 'r'));
```

In `script_2.php` I've tried many ways to close the terminal, none worked:

```
<?php

echo 'hey';

system('exit');
exec('exit');
pclose(popen('exit','r'));
exit();
```

In all cases, after the PHP execution is finished, terminal window goes back to a normal windows `cmd.exe` window.

Comment: `cmd /k` would force the cmd command to remain even after the command it executes terminates. Why are you doing `cmd /c start cmd /k` to begin with I find it a bit odd though not too familiar with windows specific cmd patterns ?

Comment: You're right @apokryfos `/c` and `/k` can't be in a same command. By the time, I didn't know that they're opposite of each other. Removing `/k` actually works. I was wondering if there's a way to close the terminal even if it's started with `/k`

Comment: If you switch from `popen` to `proc_open` you should be able to use `proc_terminate` instead of `proc_close` to force the process to terminate. `pclose` waits for the process to terminate on its own. What might also work is to send the `exit` command to the `cmd` process but you would need to know when `php script_2.php` has finished executing otherwise `cmd` will not be ready to execute another command

Answer (score 0):

I did this & it worked for me:

```
exec('exit');
```